# Xamarin Forms iOS Release Could Not AOT

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

After upgrading Xamarin Forms to the latest, Visual Studio to the latest, and the Mac to the latest versions, we're now getting this rather cryptic message.  We've tried setting the Linker settings, rolling back some nuget packages, etc. but nothing seems to work.  Release mode only.  Anywhere else we can look for something more helpful?

```
2> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(804,3): error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/david/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxxx/7f9220ebe15e8df723b97975f4d15a93/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/32/3-Build/xxxx.iOS.exe'
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.AOTTask.ExecuteAsync () [0x00232] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/BuildTasks.mtouch.cs:256  (TaskId:254)
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask.Execute (Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks build_tasks) [0x00368] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:269  (TaskId:254)
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask.Execute (Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks build_tasks) [0x000f1] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:240  (TaskId:254)
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask.Execute (Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks build_tasks) [0x00368] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:269  (TaskId:254)
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask.Execute (Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks build_tasks) [0x000f1] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:240  (TaskId:254)
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask.Execute (Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks build_tasks) [0x00368] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:269  (TaskId:254)
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ExecuteBuildTasks>b__0 () [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:49  (TaskId:254)
```

Comment: Hi, does this bug discussion be helpful ? https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4012

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's a resolution?  The last 5 or so comments on that thread have no responses.

Comment: I am running Mac OS Catalina, Version 10.15 (19A526h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am running Mac OS Catalina, Version 10.15 (19A526h)

**Unfortunately** , current version of VS can not be fully compatible with the beta version of the Mac environment .Suggesting that using Stable version Mac OS 10.14 .

Comment: Very, very disappointing - but I ended up having to re-install the mac from scratch in order to downgrade back to Mojave.